# Detect CapsLock Press on a webPage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

How can I detect a client-side capsLock keypress...I have tried creating the following function that I wanted to launch when a key is pressed

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeCapsLock(e) {
   if (typeof capsLockON != 'undefined' && e.keyCode == 20) {
      capsLockON = !capsLockON;
      displayMsg();      
   }      
} 

//Display the message if CapsLocks is ON, otherwise conceal the message    
function displayMsg() {       
   if (capsLockON)          
      document.getElementById('divCapsWarning').style.visibility = 'visible';
        else
      document.getElementById('divCapsWarning').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
} 

</script>
</head>

<body onkeydown="changeCapsLock(event)">
```

but the onkeydown event does not fire when the CapsLock is pressed?

Comment: the above code is in a MasterPage

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function from the body onkeydown tag doesn't send the event. You will need to add that to javascript for it to send it.

```
document.body.onkeydown = changeCapsLock;
```

Comment: Thanks...I don't think this is a duplicate question.  I want to detect the actual keypress, not the state of the capsLock when the page starts...In any event, I don't understand where to put "document.body.onkeydown = changeCapsLock;". what is handling the event?

Comment: I understand now. It was a dup. Thanks